# Golang: JSON formatted byte slice

Tags: go

I'm new to Go. Currently I have two arrays that look like:

```
words: ["apple", "banana", "peach"]
freq: [2, 3, 1]
```

where "freq" stores the count of each word in "words". I hope to combine the two arrays into a Json formatted byte slice that looks like

```
[{"w":"apple","c":2},{"w":"banana","c":3},{"w":"peach","c":1}]
```

How can I achieve this goal?

Currently I've declared a struct

```
type Entry struct {
  w string
  c int
}
```

and when I loop through the two arrays, I did

```
  res := make([]byte, len(words))
  for i:=0;i<len(words);i++ {
     obj := Entry{
       w: words[i], 
       c: freq[i],
     }
     b, err := json.Marshal(obj)
     if err==nil {
        res = append(res, b...)
     }
  }

  return res // {}{}{}
```

which doesn't gives me the desired result. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update with how you're using the for loo ? Also using a []Entry within the loop is better that appending to res.

Comment: @JohnSPerayil Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json.Marshal requires the struct fields to be exported.

You can use json tags to have json with small letter keys.

```
type Entry struct {
  W string `json:"w"`
  C int `json:"c"`
}
```

Also it would be easier to use a []Entry to generate the output json.
[Sample code](https://play.golang.org/p/iGuG-bNx5O).

Comment: Thank you very much sir!